# Microphone doesn't work in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS fresh install

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, lenovo, lts, ideapad

I have lenovo ideapad 330s with ubuntu 18.04 LTS . The microphone is not working . I have checked by overriding the pin 0x13 . The speaker is fine but during a skpe or facebook call . the other person is not able to hear me.

Comment: Hi Dinesh! Have you checked for additional drivers? if you press the super key and type in drivers there's a direct link to the option to search for them.

Comment: First off install pulseaudio volume control by " sudo apt install pavucontrol " , open it and then in the "input devices " section , increase the volume of your microphone . Unfortunately it's low or even minimum by default.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi i have done it also but it doesnot work

Comment: @Rabbit it says No additional drivers available